# Font selection in XeTeX for specific characters

Tags: fonts, xetex

I just ran into another issue, I like to use gill sans very much but the number 1, lower case L and upper case I are almost indistinguisable. On the other hand I like Helvetica numbers. Is there a way to use Gill Sans for all non-numeric characters and Helvetica only for numbers [0 9] ?

Comment: I think it's likely that you just gave some of the people around here a migraine.

Comment: I did ?, that was not my intention...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can. But I only know a tricky method --- to use `\XeTeXinterchartoks` and related commands. There have been some packages, for example `xeCJK` and `ucharclasses`, that use this mechanism for multilingual support. (I wrote a few code for `xeCJK`.) For more information, you can read [XeTeX's reference](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/xetexref/XeTeX-reference.pdf).

Set `\XeTeXinterchartokenstate=1` to enable the mechanism.

There are already some predefined char classes. 0 for normal westen alphabets and symbols, 1 for CJK ideographs, 4095 for boundary (255 in older versions of XeTeX), etc. And you can use `\newXeTeXintercharclass` to allocate a new class.

Use `\XeTeXcharclass` to set the numbers to the new character class, and use `\XeTeXinterchartoks` to do the trick.

Full example:

[image: result]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\XeTeXinterchartokenstate=1
\chardef\CharNormal=0
\makeatletter
% Test for old and new versions of the latex kernel
\ifx\e@alloc@intercharclass@top\@undefined
    \chardef\CharBound=255
\else
    \chardef\CharBound=\e@alloc@intercharclass@top
\fi
\makeatother
\newXeTeXintercharclass\CharNumbers
\XeTeXcharclass`0=\CharNumbers
\XeTeXcharclass`1=\CharNumbers
\XeTeXcharclass`2=\CharNumbers
\XeTeXcharclass`3=\CharNumbers
\XeTeXcharclass`4=\CharNumbers
\XeTeXcharclass`5=\CharNumbers
\XeTeXcharclass`6=\CharNumbers
\XeTeXcharclass`7=\CharNumbers
\XeTeXcharclass`8=\CharNumbers
\XeTeXcharclass`9=\CharNumbers
\newtoks\TokSetfont
\TokSetfont={\begingroup\fontspec{Latin Modern Mono}}
\XeTeXinterchartoks\CharNormal\CharNumbers=\TokSetfont
\XeTeXinterchartoks\CharBound\CharNumbers=\TokSetfont
\XeTeXinterchartoks\CharNumbers\CharNormal={\endgroup}
\XeTeXinterchartoks\CharNumbers\CharBound={\endgroup}
\begin{document}
0123

abc123

123abc

abc123def

123abc456
\end{document}
```

BTW, this does not affect math fonts.

**Note** Code has been updated to reflect changes in XeTeX (but not actually reflected in the documentation.) If this code fails, remove the test for XeTeX version and just use `\chardef\CharBound=4095`. (There was one version of the kernel that did not have `\e@alloc@intercharclass@top` defined, but the class was still 4095.)

Comment: I second the suggestion of ucharclasses, somewhat reluctantly.  It increased my compilation time by a factor of twenty, from ten seconds to two minutes.  So now I need conditional compilation, with, among other things, special handling for the CMU Serif “~” bug.  The lack of handling of missing characters in math fonts is particularly annoying, especially for a feature that should be (as it is on OSX) a built-in feature.

Comment: Every time I try to run this (using Overleaf), exactly copy and pasting your answer, I get an error: `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [save size=80000].`, clearly an infinite recursion is happening somewhere. In fact, If I change `Latin Modern Mono` to `Arial`, then I see `Font Arial does not contain any OpenType 'Script' information.` hundreds of times in the log, indicating that the line `\TokSetfont={\begingroup\fontspec{Latin Modern Mono}}` is giving the recursion.

Comment: Also, this seems to override the Courier font which should always be used when calling `\texttt{}`. Is there a fix for that?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this works in LaTeX, but at least with Plain:

```
\font\mydigitsfont="Helvetica"
\font\mydigitssfont="Helvetica/S=7" at 7pt
\font\mydigitsssfont="Helvetica/S=5" at 5pt
\newfam\mydigitsfam
\textfont\mydigitsfam=\mydigitsfont
\scriptfont\mydigitsfam=\mydigitssfont
\scriptscriptfont\mydigitsfam=\mydigitsssfont
\XeTeXmathcode`0="0\mydigitsfam`0
\XeTeXmathcode`1="0\mydigitsfam`1
\XeTeXmathcode`2="0\mydigitsfam`2
\XeTeXmathcode`3="0\mydigitsfam`3
\XeTeXmathcode`4="0\mydigitsfam`4
\XeTeXmathcode`5="0\mydigitsfam`5
\XeTeXmathcode`6="0\mydigitsfam`6
\XeTeXmathcode`7="0\mydigitsfam`7
\XeTeXmathcode`8="0\mydigitsfam`8
\XeTeXmathcode`9="0\mydigitsfam`9
\def\mydigits{\fam\mydigitsfam\mydigitsfont}
$ 1^22^{23^3}3^1 $ 123 {\mydigits 123}
\bye
```

So, automatic only for mathmode.

Comment: This works only for math fonts, which may not be what @Gregthom want. In LaTeX, math fonts for digits can be easily changed using `\DeclareMathSymbol` in NFSS scheme, without help of XeTeX.

Comment: @Leo Liu: I managed to edit in that fact pretty much the same minute you left your comment :‑)