# How to raise a character in the whole document?

Tags: fonts, characters, raise

In my document (due to combind both Chinese and English), all (, ), [, ], etc., are all too low. Is it posibble to raise all (, ), [, ], or any characters user defines to desire height? (for ex. If I want to raise all 'z' for 3pt?)

Thank you so much!

Comment: Should the amount to raise a character depend on its size? If so, it would be best to express the desired dimension in `ex`.

Comment: yes. For convenience, I just use pt instead of ex. But if I could do this (raise a specific char for n pt), then I can raise it in any measures as I wish.

ps. In some way, I prefer to use pt than em/ex. In topography's book's discussing, most typesetting problem cannot be solved by scaling/proportional calculating. Before reading such books, I use em/ex, etc. But after reading some, I use pt now even though it is more complicated than by using em/ex.

Thank you for your reply so much. Maybe using ex is a good idea in this kind of situation. :-)

Comment: If you use XeTeX, have a look at this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10248/font-selection-in-xetex-for-specific-characters . You can use similar trick to get parens raised. It would be a little difficult to let it work with `xeCJK`. I'm sorry I've no much time for this. See also http://bbs.ctex.org/viewthread.php?tid=45054&page=3&fromuid=56635#pid400524

Answer (score 7):

As a suggestion, you can define a command to output the parens/brackets in your own format. This is inspired by `csquotes` package.

A demostration:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setCJKmainfont{MingLiU}
\newcommand*\enbracket[2][0.1ex]{%
  \raisebox{#1}{[}#2\raisebox{#1}{]}}
\begin{document}
\Large [漢字] \enbracket{漢字}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yes, this is what I use now. But is it possible that doing this without setting any specific command? Sometimes, I can't tell whether the symbols are too high or too low (it depends on what font I use). Or, is it possible to alter the char's height by editing the font itself, or any metofont's command?  Thank you

Comment: You can, certaily, edit the font yourself with fontforge etc., if it is allowed. However, it is not easy and not portable. I made a comment on using `\XeTeXinterchartoks` to solve this kind of questions, but it's not easy either. (And I've no time to write a complete example.)