# Computer Modern in XeLaTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex, unicode

I love XeLaTeX for things like

```
$a≠b$ ⇔ $ a⊧a↑Ω$
```

All days before I used DejaVu fonts and Asana-Math for unicode-math.
But today I have to get visual compability with LaTeX. So I installed Computer Modern Unicode, and all close to good, but thinks like above do not displayed in non-math mode.

Yes, I know, Computer Modern is no longer modern at all. So my question -- is it any other font, that looks close and retains power of unicode?

EDIT: Probably, I was not clean enough. I CAN use unicode arrows in math-mode. I can do it in normal mode with DejaVu, but not with Modern Computer.

Comment: I don't understand. LM fonts are similar enough with CM ones. Or you want to *use math symbols in text mode*?

Comment: Computer Modern was no longer modern 100 years before it was conceived; the term modern refers to an [18th century style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_font).

Comment: @Leo Liu Yes. Gaze at example. Double arrow is outside of math mode. Unfortutanely, I cannot attach 2 pdf files to show problem even more clearly.

Comment: @illusionoflife: Yes, it is possible to use `Latin Modern Math` even in text mode, with help of `\XeTeXinterchartoks` faculty, see my answer in [Font selection in XeTeX for specific characters](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10248/). However, it is still better to use it in math mode, for better spacing and sematic reasons.

Comment: Too complicated to cure imperfect font. But still thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Use `Latin Modern Math` as math font.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\begin{document}

$a≠b ⇔ a⊨a↑Ω$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Cleaned my question. Latin modern is nice, but unrelated to my problem.

Comment: @illusionoflife Latin Modern *is* Computer Modern, how is that not related to your question?

Comment: Latin modern is more or less a hand-vectorised computer modern, see e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1390 or http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59702

Comment: Where do you get "Latin Modern" and "Latin Modern Math"? Do you have to install it as normal system font? I have TeXLive 2013 and it is not found there.

Comment: @alfC: They're installed in TeX Live. If you use Linux, maybe you can follow the instructions in [document of texlive](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-340003.4.4) to configure your `fontconfig` library to find them.