# How to change the font of the numbers in a tex

Tags: fonts, numbering

I've read the below answer :
[Font selection in XeTeX for specific characters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10248/font-selection-in-xetex-for-specific-characters)

but I need a solution that works with `pdflatex` instead of `xetex`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's better to make your questions (and answers) self-contained rather than directing people to other pages via links.

Comment: My question clear!How to change the font of the numbers in a tex. I mean I am using a font, but I don't like it for my numbers, it there a way to use separate font for numbers, without changing to math.

Answer (score 10):

There is no correspondent in `pdflatex` of the “interchar tokens” feature of XeTeX. Making digits active for expanding them to add a font call is not a choice, as you want digits also for things like `\linebreak[2]` which would break painfully.

The only way out is to define a macro:

```
\newcommand{\printnum}[1]{{\fontfamily{...}\selectfont#1}}
```

where `...` should be the family name of the font you want to use; then, to print a number with that font, say

```
\printnum{42}
```