# Change the chapter/section/subsection label numbering font

Tags: fonts, labels, xepersian

I'm using Xepersian package in Latex. I'm typing my whole text in "XBZar" font, and digits (numbers) in "Yas" font. My concern here is the chapter/section/subsection labels.

So, by default the whole chapter/section/subsection labels are in "XBZar" font (including the text and numbering, or anything you call them). I'd like to only and only change these labels numbering font to "Yas".

Here is an example of what I've currently achived, and what I want to get.
[image]
And here is a minimal example:

```
    \documentclass{book}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{xepersian}

    \settextfont[Scale=1]{XB Zar}
    \setdigitfont[Scale=1]{Yas}
    \setlatintextfont[Scale=.98]{Times New Roman}

    \defpersianfont\Yas{Yas}
    \DeclareCaptionFormat{myformat}{{\Yas #1}#2#3}
    \captionsetup{format=myformat}

    \begin{document}

    \chapter{مقدمه (\lr{Preface})}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \section{فصل اول (\lr{First Section})}
    سلام، این یک عدد است $10.004$.
    \subsection{بخش اول}
    \flushleft
    \lr{So, I need the chapter/section/subsection numbering font to be "Yas" instead of "XBZar". I should stress that ONLY numbering not the whole label.}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!, can you help us to help you with a [minimal example that reproduces the problem](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Comment: I'll do so, but I thought it was not really needed. There is not a problem per say, It's actually a matter of what i need to do :)

Comment: To simplify copy-paste code and work on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the format of `\thechapter` , `\thesection` and `\thesubsection` to obtain the desired font for headings numbers with this trick

```
\let\oldthechapter\thechapter
\let\oldthesection\thesection
\let\oldthesubsection\thesubsection

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\begingroup \Yas \oldthechapter \endgroup}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\begingroup \Yas \oldthesection \endgroup}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\begingroup \Yas \oldthesubsection \endgroup}
```

**Code**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xepersian}

\settextfont[Scale=1]{XB Zar}
\setdigitfont[Scale=1]{Yas}
\setlatintextfont[Scale=.98]{Times New Roman}

\defpersianfont\Yas{Yas}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{myformat}{{\Yas #1}#2#3}
\captionsetup{format=myformat}

\let\oldthechapter\thechapter
\let\oldthesection\thesection
\let\oldthesubsection\thesubsection

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\begingroup \Yas \oldthechapter \endgroup}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\begingroup \Yas \oldthesection \endgroup}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\begingroup \Yas \oldthesubsection \endgroup}

\begin{document}

\chapter{مقدمه (\lr{Preface})}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\section{فصل اول (\lr{First Section})}
سلام، این یک عدد است $10.004$.
\subsection{بخش اول}

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Can I change the page numbering fonts with the same trick?

I also need to change the caption numbering fonts, such as image captions and table captions. :)

should I post this as a new question?

Comment: Same method   `\let\oldthepage\thepage` then `\renewcommand{\thepage}{\begingroup \Yas \oldthepage \endgroup}`

Comment: Sorry for being so questionable, But I also need to change the caption numbering fonts, such as image captions and table captions.  What are the commands?

Comment: Related [Font selection in XeTeX for specific characters](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10248/font-selection-in-xetex-for-specific-characters)