# How to set a particular glyph to be of a particular typeface in XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex

Suppose that I have the following XeLaTeX document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\begin{document}
Proin quis (tortor) orci. Etiam at risus et $(a + b)x$.
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to globally set, for example, the font Georgia for just the parentheses?

A similar thing could be done in the math mode with `unicode-math`. For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[range="0028]{Georgia}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\begin{document}
Proin quis (tortor) orci. Etiam at risus et $(a + b)x$.
\end{document}
```

[image: The left parenthesis is in Georgia]

Possibly related: [Font selection in XeTeX for specific characters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10248/29127)

Comment: Do you mean the text parentheses or the math parentheses? Your example has both.

Comment: @AlanMunn The text parentheses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using  `XeTeXinterchartoks` to insert the font change between characters of defined classes. I've adapted the code here from the `replace-numbers.sty` which is part of `xelatex`.

Unfortunately the XeTeX documentation on this is a bit out of date, and the character class of the boundaries has been changed to 4095. This is set to `\e@alloc@intercharclass@top` in the LaTeX kernel, so I've used this instead of a hard coded number. Thanks to the experts in chat for explaining this change.

In the example below I've added a `\color{red}` to the code to show the change clearly. This obviously should be removed for your actual use case.

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\parenfont{Linux Biolinum O}
\makeatletter
\XeTeXinterchartokenstate=1
\chardef\CharNormal=0
\ifx\e@alloc@intercharclass@top\@undefined
\chardef\CharBound=255
\else
\chardef\CharBound=\e@alloc@intercharclass@top
\fi
\newXeTeXintercharclass\CharParens
\XeTeXcharclass`(=\CharParens
\XeTeXcharclass`)=\CharParens
\newtoks\TokSetfont
\TokSetfont={\begingroup\parenfont\color{red}} % remove \color{red} for actual use
\XeTeXinterchartoks\CharNormal\CharParens=\TokSetfont
\XeTeXinterchartoks\CharBound\CharParens=\TokSetfont
\XeTeXinterchartoks\CharParens\CharNormal={\endgroup}
\XeTeXinterchartoks\CharParens\CharBound={\endgroup}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Proin quis (tortor) orci. Etiam at risus et $(a + b)x$.
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

**Problems with this code**
This code checks for older versions of the latex kernel, and sets the boundary char class appropriately for that. However, there was one version of the kernel released in which `\e@alloc@intercharclass@top` was not defined although the char class was changed. If the above code doesn't run, try replacing the following code:

```
\ifx\e@alloc@intercharclass@top\@undefined
\chardef\CharBound=255
\else
\chardef\CharBound=\e@alloc@intercharclass@top
\fi
```

with this:

```
\chardef\CharBound=4095
```

Comment: I've got the following error running your example: `Extra \endgroup. <XeTeXinterchartoks> \endgroup`.

Comment: It seems that you  have the version of the latex kernel that lacked `\e@alloc@intercharclass@top`, but in which the character class of the boundary is 4095. I'll add some comments about that case.

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you very much! By the way, what do you mean by 'boundaries' in 'the character class of the boundaries'?

Comment: @Taiki The boundary is anything between a string of characters. In the output of this document it looks like a space, but in reality it could be a box or a kern or glue or math and possibly some other elements.