# Is it possible to use \addfontfeature for specific characters?

Tags: luatex, fontspec

Is it possible to use \addfontfeature for specific characters? Something like this MWE in order to get every e of the document with double size:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\setmainfont{Latin Modern}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern}[Scale=2.0, range = {e}]

\begin{document}

Test


\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, if you use XeLaTeX. See [How to set a particular glyph to be of a particular typeface in XeLaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/331756/2693) for the general method. Since LuaLaTeX doesn't have this facility it would need to be done differently (not sure if it's possible.)

Comment: @AlanMunn; With lualatex you can to it with combo fonts, but there isn't a fontspec interface yet: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314397/defining-new-font-family-with-fontspec/314401#314401

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: are there going to be high-level command for this in the near future?

Comment: No idea, I don't know if somebody is working on it.

Answer (score 1):

In ConTeXt you can use the [fallback mechanism](http://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2016/087533.html).

```
\definefallbackfamily [mixedfont] [rm] [Latin Modern Roman] [scale=2,range=0x65,force=yes]
\definefontfamily     [mixedfont] [rm] [Latin Modern Roman]

\setupbodyfont[mixedfont]
\starttext

Test

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Your link is dead.

Comment: Sorry. It is not dead, the certificate has been revoked: SEC_ERROR_REVOKED_CERTIFICATE

Comment: @Kyle_the_hacker Changed to http.