# Is there any way one could use letters from other languages as math symbols?

Tags: math-mode, unicode-math

Just like one uses greek language symbols in math mode to denote variables, is there a way to use letters from other languages, etc. like say Hindi, Marathi, Kannada, etc. It may so happen that what I am asking involves too much work to provide a solution. In that case, I just wish to know what progress if any has been made in this direction.

I have gone through the following answers  [symbol from another font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/359287/luatex-use-single-symbol-from-other-font-in-math-mode), [variable size symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/344461/defining-a-math-symbol-of-variable-sizes-in-xetex-with-umathchardef/344462#344462)

Comment: Possibly interesting: [What packages will let me use Cyrillic characters in math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14633/134144)

Comment: If you have them set up as text fonts then it should work immediately to use them inside `\text{..}`