# Mayan Numerals in math mode

Tags: math-mode, symbols, luatex

How to use Mayan Numerals from 'BabelStone Mayan Numerals' font in math mode, with LuaLaTeX?

Comment: Just curious, why do you need it for?

Comment: To write a numeral with several digits using `matrix` enviroment without embrace them in `\text{ }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With full conversion, so no computation necessary.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontface{\mayanumerals}{BabelStoneMayanNumerals}[
  Path=./,
  Extension=.ttf,
]

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\mayanumber}{sO{}m}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF { #1 }
   {
    \ensuremath { \mathrm { \tl_upper_case:n { \int_to_base:nn { #3 } { 20 } }\sb{20} } }
   }
   {
    \tatojo_maya_number:nn { #2 } { #3 }
   }
 }

\int_const:Nn \c__tatojo_maya_start_int { "1D2E0 }
\tl_new:N \l__tatojo_maya_converted_tl
\seq_new:N \l__tatojo_maya_digits_seq

\keys_define:nn { tatojo/maya }
 {
  align      .tl_set:N = \l__tatojo_maya_align_tl,
  align      .initial:n = c,
  horizontal .bool_set:N = \l__tatojo_maya_horizontal_bool,
  horizontal .default:n = true,
  vertical   .bool_set_inverse:N = \l__tatojo_maya_horizontal_bool,
  vertical   .default:n = true,
  scale      .code:n =
   {
    \fp_compare:nT { #1 != 1 } { \addfontfeatures{Scale=#1} }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \tatojo_maya_number:nn
 {
  \mbox
   {
    % choose the font and set spacing to 0.5
    \mayanumerals
    % evaluate options
    \keys_set:nn { tatojo/maya } { #1 }
    % clear the sequence containing the digits
    \seq_clear:N \l__tatojo_maya_digits_seq
    % convert the input to base 20
    \tl_set:Nx \l__tatojo_maya_converted_tl
     {
      \int_to_base:nn { #2 } { 20 }
     }
    % fill the digit sequence
    \tl_map_function:NN \l__tatojo_maya_converted_tl \__tatojo_maya_adddigit:n
    % print the digit sequence
    \bool_if:NTF \l__tatojo_maya_horizontal_bool
     {
      \seq_use:Nn \l__tatojo_maya_digits_seq { }
     }
     {
      \begin{tabular}[\l__tatojo_maya_align_tl]{@{}c@{}}
      \shortstack[c]{ \seq_use:Nn \l__tatojo_maya_digits_seq { \\ } }
      \end{tabular}
     }
   } % close the \mbox
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__tatojo_maya_adddigit:n
 {
  \seq_put_right:Nx \l__tatojo_maya_digits_seq
   {
    \tatojo_maya_digit:n { \int_from_base:nn { #1 } { 20 } }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \tatojo_maya_digit:n
 {
  \symbol { \int_eval:n { \c__tatojo_maya_start_int + #1 } }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\mayanumber*{12414}=\mayanumber{12414}$\qquad
$\mayanumber[align=b]{12414}$\qquad
$\mayanumber[scale=0.5]{12414}$

\bigskip

\mayanumber*{123456} is \mayanumber[horizontal]{123456}

\end{document}
```

Remove the `Path` and `Extension` options if you have the font installed system-wise (possibly the name also).

As you see, one inputs `\mayanumber{<number>}` and the macros take care of the conversion. The number is converted to base 20, then each digit is converted back to base 10 in order to add it to the starting point corresponding to the Mayan digit 0.

The *-version is just a wrapper around the conversion to base 20.

The available options are

- `scale` for scaling up or down the font;
- `align` for the final alignment (in vertical aspect); default is `c`, it can be `t` or `b`
- `horizontal` for printing in horizontal aspect (`vertical` is the default, which can also be specified for clarity)

[image]

Comment: Great answer!!!!

Answer (score 1):

From [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/344461/defining-a-math-symbol-of-variable-sizes-in-xetex-with-umathchardef/344462#344462) answer by @egreg,

```
\newfontface{\babm}{BabelStone Mayan Numerals}

\DeclareRobustCommand\mcero{%
    \mathrel{\text{\normalfont\babm\symbol{"01D2E0}}}%
}
```

A MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontface{\babm}{BabelStone Mayan Numerals}

\DeclareRobustCommand\mcero{%
    \mathrel{\text{\normalfont\babm\symbol{"01D2E0}}}%
}
\DeclareRobustCommand\muno{%
    \mathrel{\text{\normalfont\babm\symbol{"01D2E1}}}%
}
\DeclareRobustCommand\monce{%
    \mathrel{\text{\normalfont\babm\symbol{"01D2EB}}}%
}
\DeclareRobustCommand\mcatorce{%
    \mathrel{\text{\normalfont\babm\symbol{"01D2EE}}}%
}

\begin{document}

$${1\text B0\text E}_{20} = \begin{matrix}
\huge\muno\\
\huge\monce\\
\huge\mcero\\
\huge\mcatorce
\end{matrix}
$$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I just used this in a paper in spanish: "Mayan Numerals with LuaLateX", https://www.academia.edu/37478266/Numerales_mayas_con_LuaLaTeX