# Numbering pages with different systems (Mayan numbers)

Tags: page-numbering

I have been using latex for a long time but I always use latex for writing documents that are not particularly special. Now, it is a bit different because I would like to to change the numbering system and I would like all pages to be numbered with Mayan numbers. I know that the command:

```
\maya{number}
```

Would give the number in mayan format. However, that would not allow me to number every page automatically unless I go page by page adding \maya{number} to every page manually.

Does anyone has any suggestion as where to look in order to get some knowledge about this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX - LaTeX! [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I adapted (read reusing) the code from [Mayan Numerals in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/452756/mayan-numerals-in-math-mode). You need XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX to compile it, as well as [BabelStone Mayan Numerals font](https://www.babelstone.co.uk/Fonts/Mayan.html). Here's the code:

```
%!TEX program = lualatex
%You can use xelatex, too
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontface{\mayanumerals}{BabelStone Mayan Numerals}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\mayanumber}{sO{}m}
{
    \IfBooleanTF { #1 }
    {
        \ensuremath { \mathrm { \tl_upper_case:n { \int_to_base:nn { #3 } { 20 } }\sb{20} } }
    }
    {
        \tatojo_maya_number:nn { #2 } { #3 }
    }
}

\int_const:Nn \c__tatojo_maya_start_int { "1D2E0 }
\tl_new:N \l__tatojo_maya_converted_tl
\seq_new:N \l__tatojo_maya_digits_seq

\keys_define:nn { tatojo/maya }
{
    align      .tl_set:N = \l__tatojo_maya_align_tl,
    align      .initial:n = c,
    horizontal .bool_set:N = \l__tatojo_maya_horizontal_bool,
    horizontal .default:n = true,
    vertical   .bool_set_inverse:N = \l__tatojo_maya_horizontal_bool,
    vertical   .default:n = true,
    scale      .code:n =
    {
        \fp_compare:nT { #1 != 1 } { \addfontfeatures{Scale=#1} }
    }
}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \tatojo_maya_number:nn
{
    \mbox
    {
        % choose the font and set spacing to 0.5
        \mayanumerals
        % evaluate options
        \keys_set:nn { tatojo/maya } { #1 }
        % clear the sequence containing the digits
        \seq_clear:N \l__tatojo_maya_digits_seq
        % convert the input to base 20
        \tl_set:Nx \l__tatojo_maya_converted_tl
        {
            \int_to_base:nn { #2 } { 20 }
        }
        % fill the digit sequence
        \tl_map_function:NN \l__tatojo_maya_converted_tl \__tatojo_maya_adddigit:n
        % print the digit sequence
        \bool_if:NTF \l__tatojo_maya_horizontal_bool
        {
            \seq_use:Nn \l__tatojo_maya_digits_seq { }
        }
        {
            \begin{tabular}[\l__tatojo_maya_align_tl]{@{}c@{}}
                \shortstack[c]{ \seq_use:Nn \l__tatojo_maya_digits_seq { \\ } }
            \end{tabular}
        }
    } % close the \mbox
}

\cs_new:Nn \__tatojo_maya_adddigit:n
{
    \seq_put_right:Nx \l__tatojo_maya_digits_seq
    {
        \tatojo_maya_digit:n { \int_from_base:nn { #1 } { 20 } }
    }
}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \tatojo_maya_digit:n
{
    \symbol { \int_eval:n { \c__tatojo_maya_start_int + #1 } }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff
%And here's the magic
\renewcommand{\thepage}{$\mayanumber[horizontal,scale=3]{\arabic{page}}$}
\begin{document}
\Huge
\input tufte
\input knuth
\input knuth
\input tufte
\input knuth
\input knuth
\end{document}
```

Now we go to the document and, *voilà*, Mayan numerals.
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. This is easy to use. Thank you.

Comment: Please don't forget to mark this answer as useful if this helped you.