# Quran package with Hussaini Nastaleeq font

Tags: fonts, symbols, arabic, arabxetex

It's recommended (from the documentation) to use Amiri or Scheherazade font for the `quran` package, but I want to try different font in this case [Hussaini Nastaleeq](https://github.com/khaledhosny/hussaini-nastaleeq). Consider this code.

```
\documentclass[b5paper,11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[left=1.8cm,right=1.8cm,top=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{arabxetex}
\usepackage[uthmani]{quran}

\newcommand{\Amiri}{\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Language=Arabic,Script=Arabic]{Amiri}}
\newcommand{\Huss}{\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Language=Arabic,Script=Arabic]{Hussaini Nastaleeq}}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Amiri:
\medskip
\begin{arab}
\noindent\quransurah*[1]
\end{arab}

\medskip\medskip
\noindent
Hussaini Nastaleeq:
\medskip
\Huss
\begin{arab}
\noindent\quransurah*[1]
\end{arab}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

As we can see, the ornate parentheses are not properly shown for the Hussaini Nastaleeq font. In order to overcome this problem, I made the following workaround.

```
\documentclass[b5paper,11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[left=1.8cm,right=1.8cm,top=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{arabxetex}
\usepackage[uthmani]{quran}
\usepackage{bidi}

\newcommand{\Amiri}{\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Language=Arabic,Script=Arabic]{Amiri}}
\newcommand{\Huss}{\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Language=Arabic,Script=Arabic]{Hussaini Nastaleeq}}
\newcommand{\HNMrk}[1]{\Amiri\textarab{\symbol{"FD3F}}\Huss\textarab{#1}\Amiri\textarab{\symbol{"FD3E}}\Huss}
\newcommand{\AHN}[2]{\Huss\textarab{\ToggleAyahNumber\quranayah[#1][#2]}\HNMrk{#2}}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Amiri:
\medskip
\begin{arab}
\noindent\quransurah*[1]
\end{arab}

\medskip\medskip
\noindent
Hussaini Nastaleeq:
\medskip

\setRTL
\noindent\AHN{1}{1}\AHN{1}{2}\AHN{1}{3}\AHN{1}{4}\AHN{1}{5}\\\AHN{1}{6}\AHN{1}{7}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

It worked but I wonder, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You can probably use `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` with the codepoints `FD3E` and `FD3F` to define a replacement character for the ornate parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can patch the command `\qt@no` which hold ayah number and use `Amiri` font for  parentheses (the ayah numbre is also with `Amiri` font).

```
\documentclass[b5paper,11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[left=1.8cm,right=1.8cm,top=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{arabxetex}
\usepackage[uthmani]{quran}


\newfontfamily\Amiri[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\Huss[Script=Arabic]{Hussaini Nastaleeq}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Amiri:
\medskip
\begin{arab}
\noindent\Amiri\quransurah*[1]
\end{arab}

\medskip\medskip
\noindent
Hussaini Nastaleeq:
\medskip

\makeatletter
\def\qt@no#1{\begingroup\Amiri #1\endgroup}
\makeatother

\begin{arab}
\noindent\Huss\quransurah*[1]
\end{arab}

\end{document}
```

**Update 18/07/2018**   from [Font selection in XeTeX for specific characters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10266/54817)

```
\documentclass[b5paper,11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[left=1.8cm,right=1.8cm,top=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{arabxetex}
\usepackage[uthmani]{quran}

\newfontfamily\Amiri[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\Huss[Script=Arabic]{Hussaini Nastaleeq}
\let\arabicfont\Amiri


\def\AmiriOrnOn{%
\XeTeXinterchartokenstate=1 % activate 
\chardef\CharBound=4095     % The boundary of text string

\newXeTeXintercharclass\CharNumbers 
\XeTeXcharclass`٠=\CharNumbers
\XeTeXcharclass`١=\CharNumbers
\XeTeXcharclass`٢=\CharNumbers
\XeTeXcharclass`٣=\CharNumbers
\XeTeXcharclass`٤=\CharNumbers
\XeTeXcharclass`٥=\CharNumbers
\XeTeXcharclass`٦=\CharNumbers
\XeTeXcharclass`٧=\CharNumbers
\XeTeXcharclass`٨=\CharNumbers
\XeTeXcharclass`٩=\CharNumbers

\newXeTeXintercharclass\rightpcharclass
\newXeTeXintercharclass\leftpcharclass

\XeTeXcharclass"FD3F=\rightpcharclass
\XeTeXcharclass"FD3E=\leftpcharclass

\newtoks\TokSetfont
\TokSetfont={\begingroup\Amiri}
\XeTeXinterchartoks\CharBound\rightpcharclass=\TokSetfont
\XeTeXinterchartoks\rightpcharclass\CharNumbers={\endgroup}

\XeTeXinterchartoks\CharNumbers\leftpcharclass=\TokSetfont
\XeTeXinterchartoks\leftpcharclass\CharBound={\endgroup}
}

\def\AmiriOrnOff{\XeTeXinterchartokenstate=0} % deactivate


\begin{document}
\noindent
Amiri:
\medskip
\begin{arab}
\noindent\Amiri\quransurah*[1]
\end{arab}


\bigskip
\noindent
Hussaini Nastaleeq: % only  parentheses (of ayah number) from amiri  
\medskip

\AmiriOrnOn

\begin{arab}
\noindent\Huss\quransurah*[1]
\end{arab}

\AmiriOrnOff


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is nice, but retaining the font for the ayah number is crucial

Comment: You need to add `\begingroup\Amiri` before `\char"FD3F` and  `\char"FD3E` and to add `\endgroup` after them

Comment: I will update my answer If  I have enough time.

Comment: @SalimBou , two codes didn't work with me